# Sending corporate email with Python: TimeoutError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to send an email using a corporate email address with `smtplib` in Python 3.7.
Here's my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

from_addr='myEmail@corporate.com'
to_addr='myEmail@corporate.com'

server = smtplib.SMTP('corporateServer', 'port')
server.starttls()
msg = MIMEText('send my python', 'plain', 'utf-8')
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 51, in
<module>
     server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer, 25)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py",
 line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py",
 line 336, in connect
     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py",
 line 307, in _get_socket
     self.source_address)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
     raise err   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
     sock.connect(sa) TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Comment: The script is timing out while trying to connect to the SMTP server (server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServer, 25)). Did you try connecting to the server using telnet or some other tool?

Comment: Yes, tested with telnet-operation timed out, unable to connect to remote host and ping-request timeout. But 3rd party tools are able to send emails with same serverName and port details.

Comment: What port are you using? Did you try to connect using port 587 or 465? Also did you verify that you're using the correct mail server (nslookup -type=mx website.com)?

Comment: I was using port=25 confirmed by out IT admin; just now tried with 587 and 465, same error. When I did nslookup for mx, getting result as mxa-002fd301.gslb.pphosted.com, which is in similar format but not exact servername.

Comment: Could you have a firewall on your local machine? I once fell into a close problem because the firewall knew about thunderbird and Outlook, but rejected connections from my own program...